# Generating a download link/export file (csv or excell)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i need some advice, i need to be able to generate a download link, and in this download link i can export some table data store in my database(questions ans answers ). I need to be able to get the data from the controller, and then return the generate link.

But there is a thing about it. For example these links will be sent to the client(cronjob), every day ex(ex: data from "2017-06-06 00:00:00" to "2017-06-06 24:59:59". Can someone tell me a good toll/repo that can make me achieve what im trying to do?

My example route downlo: `ex: domain.com/download/uniquehaskkey/dateRangeMaybe..`"

Comment: Have you checked this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling ?

Comment: use this package with laravel shceduling 
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel